# Postfix ошибка отправки

Tags: postfix

Такая проблема. Развернул на Debian 11 VPS, установил nginx, postfix, dovecot и roundcube. Письма отправить могу, веб интерфейс вижу, письма, кстати, доходят, но если я отправляю письмо на свою VPS, то не письмо не приходит. Через команду смотрю и наблюдаю следующее:

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log
Jul 31 11:46:48 brusnika postfix/smtpd[114235]: error: open database /etc/postfix/sender_access.db: No such file or directory
Jul 31 11:46:48 brusnika postfix/smtpd[114235]: connect from forward400b.mail.yandex.net[178.154.239.159]
Jul 31 11:46:48 brusnika postfix/trivial-rewrite[114239]: warning: do not list domain brusnika.fun in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Jul 31 11:46:48 brusnika postfix/smtpd[114235]: warning: hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access is unavailable. open database /etc/postfix/sender_access.db: No such file or directory
Jul 31 11:46:48 brusnika postfix/smtpd[114235]: warning: hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access lookup error for "test.brusnika@yandex.ru"
Jul 31 11:46:48 brusnika postfix/smtpd[114235]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from forward400b.mail.yandex.net[178.154.239.159]: 451 4.3.5 <test.brusnika@yandex.ru>: Sender address rejected: Server configuration error; from=<test.brusnika@yandex.ru> to=<test@brusnika.fun> proto=ESMTP helo=<forward400b.mail.yandex.net>
Jul 31 11:46:48 brusnika postfix/smtpd[114235]: disconnect from forward400b.mail.yandex.net[178.154.239.159] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=6/8
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: postmap забыли выполнить?

Comment: @andreymal прошу прощения, а как его выполнить или узнать выполняется ли он?

Comment: Это должно было упоминаться в той инструкции, из которой вы взяли этот самый `/etc/postfix/sender_access`

Comment: К сожалению такого упоминания не было. В инструкции описано следующее:
1)В Postfix добавить правило check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
2)После создать сам файл /etc/postfix/sender_access
3)Ну и перезагрузить Postfix systemctl restart postfix

Comment: Значит хреновая инструкция какая-то, ну в общем после каждого изменения подобных файлов нужно выполнять команду `postmap /etc/postfix/sender_access` чтобы создался/обновился файл `/etc/postfix/sender_access.db` соответственно

Comment: А если нет файла /etc/postfix/sender_access.db
Но есть простой файл /etc/postfix/sender_access
Надо его создать?

Comment: postmap его и создаёт

Comment: @andreymal Сработало, спасибо большое) 
Только проблема осталась, я проверил, у меня в конфиге dovecot была синтаксическая ошибка, я ее поправил и запустил dovecot, но письма все равно не приходят((